# the_content() printing site title after page/post title and before its content

Tags: the-content

My pages are all showing the Site Title (from the Customizer) after the page or post title and before the "body" of the post. Troubleshooting by injecting lines of text to print before and after WordPress code narrows the source down to the `the_content()` call within the page template.

Here's how `the_content()` is called:

```
        ...
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="content entry-content">
            <?php the_content(
                // Translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers.
                sprintf( esc_html__( 'Continue reading %s', 'bulmapress' ), '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . the_title( '', '', false ) . '</span>' )
            );

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'bulmapress' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
                ) );
                ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

        <footer class="content entry-footer">
        ...
```

I'm a bit baffled because `post_template.php` where `the_content()` and `get_the_content()` are defined is a WordPress /includes file, not a parent theme file.

Should I be looking for some filter that's been defined in the theme?
TIA

Comment: `esc_html__` in the first param of `sprintf` might lead to unexpected results, I think. Try removing that, or moving it to the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried removing all params from the_content() and it works just the same (content and site title).

Comment: I looked for all instances of `add_filter(` in the parent theme. There are two, and neither has anything to do with the site title.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit was within an add_filter function. Commenting out the following removed the site title from above the page/post content:

```
function add_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) {
        $content .= '<p>This article is copyright &copy; '.date('Y').'&nbsp;'.bloginfo('name').'</p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

The first part, "This article is copyright (c)", printed where you'd expect, but bloginfo('name') was appearing *before* the rest of the content.

Edit -- explanation:

In the [WordPress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/#more-information), some cryptic advice appears: "This always prints a result to the browser. If you need the values for use in PHP, use get_bloginfo()." `Bloginfo()` consists of an `echo` statement, so it prints to the browser *immediately* while the code is being pre-processed.

My call to `bloginfo()` within a function in my child theme's `functions.php` was processed before WordPress had a chance to print the page's or post's content, so that's when the output of the function appeared. Instead, `get_bloginfo()` only returns the data corresponding to the requested argument.

Comment: Oh I see. `bloginfo` outputs. You should have used `get_bloginfo`.